# Sublime text conflict with systems's locale

Tags: 16.04, sublime-text

With the new sublime text version I receive:

"Package Control

Your system's locale is set to a value that can not handle non-ASCII characters. Package Control can not properly work unless this is fixed.

On Linux, please reference your distribution's docs for information on properly setting the LANG environmental variable. As a temporary work-around, you can launch Sublime Text from the terminal with:

LANG=en_US.UTF-8 sublime_text"

How can I get around this?

My locale is:

```
LANG=de_CH.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=de_CH:de
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_PAPER="C"
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=C
```

[image]

Comment: What is your locale? You can see it from `locale` in a terminal.

Comment: @dadexix86: Added above.

Comment: That's the problem. C is not good enough for sublime text. Did you use something like localepurge?

Comment: I don't know what that is, I'm more of a hobbyist.

Comment: It's a program to remove locales, in order to free some space on the computer. That are the settings in Language Support? Can you post the two screenshots please?

Comment: Pardon: What screenshots do you want me to post?

Comment: I am not sure about the title in English, I think it might be something like Language settings, or Language support. There are two tabs there, I need the both.

Comment: From Ubuntu system settings? See the screenshot above. I'm not sure if it's that what you want.

Comment: @dadexix86: _Language Support_ won't help in this case. The problem is that `LC_ALL` is set, and it wasn't done via _Language Support_.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `LC_ALL` is set to "C" somewhere. `LC_ALL` should not be set persistently at all on an Ubuntu desktop. If it is, it overrides any GUI for setting locales/language.

I'd start to check out the `/etc/default/locale` file. If you find the line

```
LC_ALL=C
```

there, then open the file for editing, remove that line, and relogin.

Comment: It says: LANG="de_CH.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="de_CH:de"

Comment: @empedokles: In that case you have set `LC_ALL` in some other config file. If you fail to find out where, one way to handle it might be to add the line `unset LC_ALL` to your `~/.profile` file (and relogin).

Comment: How can I find this file? I don't remember to have set it. I upgraded from 15.10 to 16.04.

Comment: @empedokles: `~` stands for your home directory (`/home/<yourname>`), so you find `.profile` in the 'root' of your home directory. (It's a hidden file, so if you use _Files_, you need to make sure that it also shows hidden files.)

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. BTW: The same problem on my laptop, seems ubuntu-specific.